# Multiple war build with ant

Tags: java, web-applications, ant, build, war

I wrote a simple python script which changes some configurations in a java project. Then, the script invokes an ant script to build the .war file and move it into a different folder.

I have to build several .war file with different configurations.
Everything works fine, if i run the script manually, one config at the time.

If i loop over the configurations, instead, all the war files i create and copy have the same config of the last war created!

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Here my ant build (names are obscured for business reasons)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Deploy From Eclipse to JBoss" basedir="." default="deploy">
  <!-- This replace with yours project name and JBoss location: -->
  <property name="warfile" value="xxx"/>
  <property name="deploy" value="C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\tmp"/>
  <target name="create">
      <war destfile="${warfile}.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" update="true">
        <classes dir="build\classes"/>
        <fileset dir="WebContent">
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
        </fileset>
      </war>
  </target>
  <target name="copy">
      <copy todir="${deploy}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
          <include name="${warfile}.war"/>
        </fileset>
      </copy>
  </target>
  <target name="clear">
      <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${deploy}" defaultexcludes="false">
          <include name="${warfile}.*/**" />
        </fileset>
      </delete>
  </target>
  <target name="deploy">
      <antcall target="create"/>
      <antcall target="clear"/>
      <antcall target="copy"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

And here there is a snippet of the pyhon code

```
'''setup the base info for the changes in the settings'''
for c in c_dict:
  '''...apply the changes to the required files...'''
  final_output_path = outputpath+country+"\\xxx.war"
  os.system("ant -f ../build.xml")
  copyfile(starting_location, final_output_path)
  os.remove(starting_location)
```

To be more clear: if i call the script without the loop, so if I run it for each configuration by specifying it, everything works.

If i put the loop, all the war file are created with the last configuration of the loop.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest an alternative approach that avoids python programs to launch ANT?

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── moduleA
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── build.xml
└── moduleB
    ├── build.properties
    └── build.xml
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="parent" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <subant>
      <filelist dir=".">
        <file name="moduleA/build.xml"/>
        <file name="moduleB/build.xml"/>
      </filelist>
      <target name="clean"/>
      <target name="build"/>
    </subant>
  </target>

</project>
```

### moduleA/build.xml

Each build file imports a local properties for that sub-project

```
<project name="module" default="build">

  <property file="build.properties"/>

  ..
  ..
</project>
```